# Sum of the fractions of zeros correctly predicted - Testing Goodness of fit (R Studio)

Tags: r

In Kennedys guide to econometrics he discusses several problems with both R-squared and using the popular Goodness of fit measure of percentage of cases correctly predicted.

Kennedy says:

> A better measure along these lines is the sum of the fraction of zeros correctly predicted plus the fraction of ones correctly predicted, a number which should exceed unity if the prediction method is of value. ( p. 267 Kennedy, A Guide to Econometrics 5th ed)

I wanted to know whether this method alluded to has become an accredited approach to assessing goodness of fit and whether it has an implementation in R (if so, using which packages?)I can't access the textbook so cannot follow this up directly in the book.

With my current research I feel I am being (rightly no doubt) cautioned regarding the use of all methods and measures but not really pointed in a better direction. Knowing the limitations is important I admit, but making a decision regarding the most effective measure is too.

Does anybody have any experience of the method suggested by Kennedy?

Comment: Hi @Imo, whilst I follow where you're going, I'd say that it relates to R insofar as I'm wondering if there's a package out there which does it. I can see why you think the rest of it is broadish but my real interest here is executing it in the R environment.

Comment: Note that package requests are explicitly off topic on SO. You can read through a list of packages by subject type on [CRAN taskViews](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this method, but based off what you describe, but my understanding is that this is a method to assess the quality of a binary model, i.e. a model that is used to predict a YES/NO or 0/1 type outcome.

If you would simply toss a coin to predict a binary outcome with an underlying *B(n, 0.5)* distribution, you would expect to predict right 50% of the time. This means you would on average predict 50% of the Ones right and 50% of the Zeros right. If you were to then use the Kenndy method, you would get that the sum of the percentages of cases correctly predicted would add up to 1 - this is why he says that the statistic should *exceed* 1 - basically it should be better than a coin toss.

I think you could implement it in R with the following user-defined function:

```
kennedy2<-function(prediction, reality){
  perc1<-length(intersect(which(prediction==1),
                          which(reality==1)))/length(which(reality==1))
  perc2<-length(intersect(which(prediction==0),
                          which(reality==0)))/length(which(reality==0))
  return(sum(perc1, perc2))
}
```

This should work if your predicted values and the observed values have the same index. To see whether this is what you were looking for, consider the following example. The model in this example is a very simple Linear Probability Model, I am sure there is better code for this. The object is to test whether using the GPA and the GRE of a student, we can correctly predict his admission (YES/NO outcome):

```
reslm<-lm(admit~gpa+gre)
pred<-rep(0,length(reslm$fitted.values))
for (i in 1:(length(reslm$fitted.values))){
  if(reslm$fitted.values[i]>.5){
    pred[i]<-1
  }else{pred[i]<-0}
}
stat<-kennedy2(pred, admit)

pred2<-rep(0,length(reslm$fitted.values))
for (i in 1:(length(reslm$fitted.values))){
  if(reslm$fitted.values[i]>.4){
    pred2[i]<-1
  }else{pred2[i]<-0}
}
stat2<-kennedy2(pred2, admit)

pred3<-rep(0,length(reslm$fitted.values))
for (i in 1:(length(reslm$fitted.values))){
  if(reslm$fitted.values[i]>.3){
    pred3[i]<-1
  }else{pred3[i]<-0}
}
stat3<-kennedy2(pred3, admit)
```

If you change the cutoff value for the prediction a bit (.5, .4, .3), you can see that the Kennedy statistic improves, i.e. the model is correct more frequently.

Comment: Thank you for the code.  It doesn't appear to answer the question, though, which is not about how to perform the calculation, but whether and under what circumstances it might be appropriate to use.

Comment: Sorry, when the question originally appeared on stackoverflow, I thought the asker was interested in the implementation rather than the merits of the method.

Comment: @FelixSchleef Massive thanks for putting that together - you are right that I am also interested in the implementation in R. I am trying to run the example you have given. It doesn't recognise the object 'pred' so I changed all instances of 'pred' to mydata$pred.  Does that make sense? Then when I run the function with `stat <-kennedy(mydata$pred, mydata$admit)` I get a value returned to me of 1.02892076, which I don't quite understand. Have I massively misunderstood the way the function is working here?

Comment: I hope this is correct and helps :)